# How can we pass custom parameters in predefined and Custom Events of Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook-analytics

I want to trigger event on user registration like this
 FB.AppEvents.logEvent("Registration");

but how can I pass both the **valueToSum** and **parameters arguments** to this custom Event?

and likewise How can I pass custom parameters to my predefined Events like  FB.AppEvents.EventNames.ADDED_TO_CART?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(
  FB.AppEvents.EventNames.COMPLETED_REGISTRATION,
  valueToSum /* number */,
  customParams /* Object */
);
```

I'd recommend using `FB.AppEvents.EventNames.COMPLETED_REGISTRATION` instead of `"Registration"` since it's one of the predefined events.

The above example also shows how to pass custom parameters to predefined events.

You can find more information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/web

Out of curiosity, what do you need `valueToSum` for on a registration event? Registration typically isn't something that needs an aggregate value.

Comment: Registration was an example, Like I want to trigger an Custom event on click on button "Product Detail". Since it is not predefined Event, now I need to pass parameters to this event. FB.AppEvents.logEvent("Product_Detail")

Comment: Ok, you can do that with `FB.AppEvents.logEvent("Product_Detail", valueToSum, {customParam1: customValue1, ...})`